# Forking a question, because answers pre and post edit are significantly different.

Tags: support, questions

Query for a mod: [How can DMs effectively telegraph specific dangers in D&D?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-can-danger-be-effectively-telegraphed-in-dd/3549#3549) is no longer relevant as an answer for the edited question, but as many of the answers are answering the "tone" question rather than the "accurate intel" question, what's the best way to fork the question into a new question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question has been edited so that your given answer is no longer relevant, but you still feel that the question you originally answered was valuable to the community, you could delete your answer to the "old" question and then create and answer your own separate question.

Just my $0.02

Answer (score 2):

Delete your old answer if you think it's not relevant. Start a new question and ask it differently.  If you really care about the question, that is - it wasn't your question in the first place, so there's not necessarily a reason to start a fork of it unless you really want to know (asking questions for shits and grins is frowned upon, by me at least).

Comment: It's not my old question. That's the problem. [How can DMs effectively telegraph specific dangers in D&D?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3548/how-can-danger-be-effectively-telegraphed-in-dd) is what I'm discussing. The answers have forked pretty significantly pre/post edit.

Comment: People are responsible for editing their questions

Comment: @Jeremiah I'm not sure what you mean to imply in this context when you say that?